# How to change the default blue-color in `densCols` in R?

Tags: r, colors

`densCols` as part of the `grDevices` in R base by default gives a blue color determined by `blues9`. I was wondering if there might be a way we could change `blues9` to any different color while maintaining the `densCols` effect?

Notice, I need a single color.

As an example, how can we change the blue-color in the plot given by the following R code:

```
x = rnorm(1e4, 2, 1) ; y = rnorm(1e4, 1, 2)
plot(x, y, col = densCols(x, y, colramp = colorRampPalette(blues9[-(1:3)])) )
```

Comment: Hmm you can change it to any color ramp you want, e.g. `plot(x, y, col = densCols(x, y, colramp = colorRampPalette(c("lightgreen","yellow","orange","red"))) )`. Or did I get you wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?colorRampPalette`. You can pass any vector of colour names or values to the function. The default `blues9[-(1:3)]` just passes the last 6 elements of the 9-element vector of colour values, `blues9`.

For example, using the `Greens` palette from `RColorBrewer`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
plot(x, y, col = densCols(x, y, colramp = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Greens"))))
```